# Solve this Diophantine equations $(2^x-1)(3^y-1)=2z^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

> Find the positive integers $(2^x-1)(3^y-1)=2z^2$ have three solution
>   $$(1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,5,11)$$

I already know the solution of $(2^x-1)(3^y-1)=z^2$ has no solution.see:P.G.Walsh December 2006 [On Diophantine equations of the form](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/gwalsh/slov1.pdf) but there is a factor of 2 that seems complicated(I also searched a lot of these articles, and I didn't find any questions about the coefficient of 2,3,4 on the right.) and I didn't know anyone had studied this before. If so, please help me with the article or link,Thanks
 Before I have post this problem on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296729/solve-this-diophantine-equations-2x-13y-1-2z2)

Comment: For $1\le x,y\le 10^4$ , no further solution exists.

Comment: It looks like the comments over on MO should guide you to a proof.

Comment: This seems to be answered in the [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296729/solve-this-diophantine-equations-2x-13y-1-2z2) post.