# Solutions of $10^{x} -5^{x}-2^{x}=y^{2}-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do i show that the only positive integral solutions to the equation $$10^{x} -5^{x}-2^{x}=y^{2}-1$$ are $(x,y)=(1,2)$.

Tried a lot of things. This looks quite difficult and i am not even sure how to start.

Comment: $10^x-5^x-2^x+1=5^x(2^x-1)-(2^x-1)=(2^x-1)(5^x-1)=y^2$ possibly helpful.

Comment: the  equation has  positive integral solutions if and only if $\left( {{2}^{x}}-1 \right)\left( {{5}^{x}}-1 \right)$ is a perfect square

Comment: No further solution for $x\le 10^5$

Comment: [A related manuscript](http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/gwalsh/slov1.pdf). Linked to earlier in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2717395/11619).

Comment: I suggest you to ask this question: How to proof $\left( {{2}^{x}}-1 \right)\left( {{5}^{x}}-1 \right)$ is not a perfect square number for $x>1$.

Comment: If you look at the equation $(2^x-1)(5^x-1)=y^2 \mod{3}$, since $5\equiv2\mod{3}$, you get $(2^x-1)^2\equiv y^2\mod{3}$. If I can find a proof based on this, I will post it.