# Is $\left( {{2}^{x}}-1 \right)\left( {{5}^{x}}-1 \right)$ a square number for integer $x>1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852585/solutions-of-10x-5x-2x-y2-1).

> How to prove that $\left( {{2}^{x}}-1 \right)\left( {{5}^{x}}-1 \right)$ is not a  square number for integer $x>1$?

Thanks for any suggestions.

*Edition by the notification of @gimusi:*

The answer of this post that is mentioned by @crskhr,  is provided by the dear user [@Robert Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299698/robert-z).

Thanks to all users that have been contributed in this post.

Comment: Removed the **perfect-numbers** tag, as this question has got nothing to do with perfect numbers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- This is **Problem 12019** in the American Math Monthly. A solution can be found in the link: **[AMM 12019](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM12019.pdf)**

Comment: Is it possible to ask you how to search to find this pdf files? Thanks

Comment: I was lucky to have seen this question before in AMM and was quick to show you a reference :)

Comment: I appreciate you for addressing the link.

Comment: By the way the solution provided is from the user  @RobertZ. Many others solution a study material is available in his website, I highly suggest that as a great reference.

Comment: @gimusi I don't see anyone by the name RobertZ in the MSE users list :(

Comment: @crskhr Here is https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299698/robert-z

Comment: @gimusi Ah, i missed the space :) Thanks a ton!